# Questions about the html table

Tags: html, css, frontend, thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FGM0.png)I have a question about the table in html. I've been having a headache for three days trying to solve this problem and asked several questions, but it hasn't been resolved. I'd really appreciate your help.
I want to use the table tag and th:each to display the list. The  used in the list is one thing (i.e. the fields from the table in db are one thing), and I would like to list the table all the way in two columns. However, if you use the table tag, you can see only one field in a line. In other words, my goal of showing two fields per line does not apply.
How can I solve this problem?
(Image: Design I want)

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
<table th:each="Vocalist: ${bookLis}">
                <td>
                    <div class="bookdiv" id="startButton">
                        <img src="images/ClosedBook.png" class="closeBook">
                        <span class="bookName" th:text="${Vocalist.vocaName}">title</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
        </table>
```

I also used the grid of css but it didn't work out.

Comment: You don't have any rows here.  You need `<tr>` tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this updated code with `<tr>` tag for handling rows in your table:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="vocalist, iterStat : ${bookList}" th:if="${iterStat.index % 2 == 0}">
        <td>
            <div class="bookdiv" id="startButton">
                <img src="images/ClosedBook.png" class="closeBook">
                <span class="bookName" th:text="${vocalist.vocaName}">title</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td th:if="${iterStat.index + 1 &lt; bookList.size()}">
            <div class="bookdiv" id="startButton">
                <img src="images/ClosedBook.png" class="closeBook">
                <span class="bookName" th:text="${bookList[iterStat.index + 1].vocaName}">title</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where did all that additional code, that isn't present in OP's question, come from?

Comment: additional code is provided just for more clarification. @gre_gor

Comment: <td th:if="${iterStat.index + 1 &lt; bookList.size()}"> is a part of the Thymeleaf template code, and it's used to conditionally include a <td> element in the HTML output.

Comment: more information on Thymelead can be found on this link: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: thank you for answer, but I ran it by applying html with the code you gave me, and this time no td appeared on the screen. I'm sorry, but can I ask for additional help?

Comment: When running with the code you wrote in the text, only one td was created per line, but all td came out normally.

Comment: sure, you can ask for it. let me recheck my code snippet

Comment: code i provided is surely for two tds in one line. the code you provided and problem you shared both are differnet scenarios, the picture you provided explains about even and odd sorting in tables, but the description & code you provided donot match the picture. Please explain what actual the issue is!

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I will revise the code you wrote to suit my code and run it again. If there is another problem, or when it is resolved, I will comment again. (Because I can't run the code right now.) Thank you very, truly for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: very welcome dear, happy learning.

Comment: Hello! Thanks to you, the problem has been completely cleared. Once again, thank you very much for your help...!!!